# writing xml in web.sitemap file by using xmlwriter

Tags: c#, sitemap

I have web.sitemap file defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="">

    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

I am trying to write xml by using the below code

```
var writer = new XmlTextWriter("/Web.sitemap", null);

var xmlElements = new XElement("siteMapNode",
    new XAttribute("title", "Movies"),
    movies.Select(i => new XElement
        ("siteMapNode",
        new XAttribute("title", i.MovieName),
        new XAttribute("url", string.Format("/Movie/{0}.html", i.MovieName))
        )));


writer.WriteString(xmlElements.ToString());
```

But the file remain as before, the above code did not write anything. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

1) First of all, as `XmlTextWriter` is disposable, it is good to `Dispose` it (for example with `using` statement). If you add it to your code, file will be written, but...

2) Combination of `WriteString` and `XmlTextWriter` apparently produces escaped tags

```
&lt;siteMapNode title="Movies"&gt;
  &lt;siteMapNode title="Rambo" url="/Movie/Rambo.html" /&gt;
&lt;/siteMapNode&gt;
```

so I suggest changing `writer.WriteString(xmlElements.ToString());` to `xmlElements.Save(writer);`. But...

3) You do not format you XML correctly because root is `siteMapNode` and should be `siteMap`

Final code:

```
List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>() { new Movie() { MovieName = "Rambo" } };
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter("Web.sitemap", null))
{
    var xmlElements = new XElement("siteMap",
        new XAttribute("title", "Movies"),
        movies.Select(i => new XElement
            ("siteMapNode",
            new XAttribute("title", i.MovieName),
            new XAttribute("url", string.Format("/Movie/{0}.html", i.MovieName))
            )));
    xmlElements.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: thinking like give 100 points for this. Nice Explanation Dude